# SFTP adapter in BizTalk2013R2, is it possible to produce a log?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

Iur BizTalk appears received duplicated messages from the partner SFTP site, we are trying to find out if it is the partner's fault posted the duplicated files or if it is BizTalk magically introduced the duplication. Unfortunately the SFTP site log was purged. In FTP adapter, it has an option to configure a log path for this kind of purpose, but it seems not available for the BizTalk SFTP adapter.

Any thought?

Comment: I don't believe so - but perhaps did you recently add another host and forget to cluster the host the adapter is running on?

Comment: Unfortunately they failed to implement a bit off functionality in the SFTP adapter including ReadOnly files, Proxy Settings, SSO and Logging.    As Dan says, make sure your SFTP is running on a clustered host, also check for any other receive location pointing to the same location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer is this is not yet implemented

Comment: We have to use third party adapter for this, we picked /n software which can fits the requirement

Answer (score 0):

Logging is not available in BizTalk 2013 R2, it will however be available in BizTalk 2016.

[BizTalk Server 2016 What's New](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt670742)

> SFTP adapter supports more SFTP servers, and has more encryption ciphers and **logging**. It also uses WinSCP to connect to SFTP servers.